# Parametrisation of an elliptical paraboloid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

Is there a way to parameterise $x+y^2+2z^2=4$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$ (i.e. similar to cylindrical coordinates)?

Comment: Given an $r$ and a $\theta$, how many points on the surface has those two coordinates? For easy parametrisation, the answer ought to be "always exactly $1$".

Comment: If you can relax your restrictions a little, make the substitution $y=r\cos\theta,\quad z=r\sin\theta$...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use

$$\begin{cases}x=4-(r\cos\theta)^2-2(2r\sin\theta)^2\\y=r\cos\theta\\z=2r\sin\theta\end{cases}$$

with $r\ge0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$.